# Is it possible to use ANSI color escape codes in Bash here-documents?

Tags: bash, colors, escape-characters

I'm printing a message in a Bash script, and I want to colourise a portion of it; for example,

```
#!/bin/bash

normal='\e[0m'
yellow='\e[33m'
cat <<- EOF
    ${yellow}Warning:${normal} This script repo is currently located in:
    [ more messages... ]
EOF
```

But when I run in the terminal (`tmux` inside `gnome-terminal`) the [ANSI escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are just printed in `\` form; for example,

```
\e[33mWarning\e[0m This scr....
```

If I move the portion I want to colourise into a `printf` command outside the here-doc, it works.  For example, this works:

```
printf "${yellow}Warning:${normal}"
cat <<- EOF
    This script repo is currently located in:
    [ more messages... ]
EOF
```

From `man bash` – Here Documents:

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on *word*. If any characters in *word* are quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.  In the latter case, the character sequence **\<newline>** is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

I can't work out how this would affect ANSI escape codes. Is it possible to use ANSI escape codes in a Bash here document that is `cat`ted out?

Comment: I don't *think* this has anything to do with here documents. Your variable contains the literal string `\e[33m` and is substituted normally in both cases. If you have some reason to think it's confined to heredocs, or a bit of real code that shows the behaviour you're interested in, please [edit] it in.

Comment: Either `yellow=$'\e[33m'` or `yellow=$(printf '\e[33m')` (as you're already doing) will put the escape character into the string directly to test with.

Comment: @MichaelHomer So basically the string `'\e[33m'` is meaningless to a terminal? it only has meaning to commands like `echo -e` or `printf` - which then produce the "real" code that gets sent to the terminal?

Comment: Y‌‌‌‌e‌‌‌‌s‌‌‌‌.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your script, these assignments

```
normal='\e[0m'
yellow='\e[33m'
```

put those characters *literally* into the variables, i.e., <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>, rather than the escape sequence.  You can construct an escape character using `printf` (or some versions of `echo`), e.g.,

```
normal=$(printf '\033[0m')
yellow=$(printf '\033[33m')
```

but you would do much better to use `tput`, as this will work for any correctly set up terminal:

```
normal=$(tput sgr0)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
```

Looking at your example, it seems that the version of `printf` you are using treats `\e` as the escape character (which may work on your system, but is not generally portable to other systems).  To see this, try

```
yellow='\e[33m'
printf 'Yellow:%s\n' $yellow
```

and you would see the *literal* characters:

```
Yellow:\e[33m
```

rather than the escape sequence.  Putting those in the `printf` format tells `printf` to interpret them (if it can).

Further reading:

- [tput,  reset  -  initialize  a  terminal or query terminfo database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)
- [printf - write formatted output](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (POSIX)

Comment: Im not understanding what you mean by *put those characters literally into the variables* - isn't that what you want? i.e. the variables just store the values until the variables are interpolated into the string?

Comment: This format didnt seem to work reliably (the `yellow` didnt  work, but the `normal` did). but the `normal=$(tput sgr0)`  format is working perfectly!

Comment: ah ok, so `printf 'Yellow:%s\n' $yellow`  produced literal characters because `printf` wasn't giving `Yellow` "special" treatment.  So the reason this works `printf "%s" "$(tput setaf 3)foo$(tput sgr0)"` is because tput is generating escape sequences the terminal can recognise directly, that's nice to know thanks!

Comment: Also `red=$'\e[31m'` in ksh93, bash, zsh, mksh, FreeBSD sh and soon POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

This assignments are not placing escaped characters in the variable:

```
normal='\e[0m'                  yellow='\e[33m'
```

To do so, you need `echo -e` `printf` or `$'...'` (in bash).

Since you are using bash, you might as well use this:

```
normal=$'\e[0m'                 yellow=$'\e[33m'
```

Please note the `$` before the string `'\e[0m'`.

However, the portable way to get escaped characters is printf, as this:

```
normal="$(printf '\033[0m')"    yellow="$(printf '\033[33m')"
```

The octal value (033) of the escape character is valid in all POSIX shells.

Comment: Note that `$'\e[0m` will be in the next major issue of the POSIX specification and is already supported in `ksh93` (where it comes from), `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh` at least.

Comment: Note that `echo -e` outputs `"-e\n"`  in POSIX compliant echo implementations. `echo '\033'` outputs an ESC character with Unix-conformant  `echo`s on ASCII-based systems.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I had the impression that a reasonable placed `printf` is a good solution. And that using printf was a way to avoid presenting, discussing and finally rejecting the use of the flawed in multiple ways `echo` command. What makes it useful to point to the command `echo` in this answer?